# TPL FromAsync Task keeps getting cancelled

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm sending 10 messages from a client to a server in a loop, and then responses back from the server to the client using TPL's FromAsync (targeting .NET 4.0)

After the last message is sent from the client, I'm trying to measure the total time taken until the final response is received. To do this, I call Task.WaitAll but I get an AggregateException who's inner exception says "A task was cancelled" for all the tasks. The server is receiving the requests.

Code:

```
private static double MeasureAsyncTPL(List<string> stringList)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var tasks = new Task[stringList.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i++)
        {
            string source = stringList[i];
            tasks[i] = SendMessageToServerAsync(source);
            //SendMessageToServerAsync(source);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);


        stopwatch.Stop();            
        return stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds; 
    }

        static Task SendMessageToServerAsync(string message)
    {
        Task task;
        var byteArray = MessageToByteArray(message, Encoding.UTF8);
        using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                task = Write(networkStream,byteArray,0);
                Task continuation = task.ContinueWith(ant => Read(ant, networkStream), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                return continuation;
            }
        }
    }

        private static Task Write(NetworkStream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginWrite, stream.EndWrite, buffer, offset, buffer.Length, null);
    }

    private static Task Read(Task write, NetworkStream stream)
    {

        byte[] data = new byte[50];
        return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead, data, 0, data.Length, null);

    }
```

The exception is being picked up inside MeasureAsyncTPL on the line `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`. How can I fix this exception?

Second question - is FromAsync inside my Read method guaranteed to return the entire message from the server? Or do I need to call it multiple times while keeping track of a the size of the byte array that the server sent?

Comment: You are disposing of the `networkStream` before writing or reading.

Comment: The cancellation is automatic for a continuation when the antecedent task is faulted and you specify the `NotOnFaulted` option, pointing to an exception in your `Write` task (as others have pointed, likely due to premature stream disposal). Fix that and you'll fix the `TaskCanceledException`.

Comment: Also, your `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent` does absolutely nothing as your task is not scheduled *inside* another task - it's just a continuation and has no parent to attach to.

Comment: If you use a continuation style task, you cant run it inside a `using` block without synchronously blocking, otherwise the element will get disposed and you'll end up with a race condition, like you're seeing now.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, solid advice, although I would extend it to *any* task which relies on the `IDisposable` being alive, not just continuations (i.e. you shouldn't return a task asynchronously reading from a `Stream` inside the `using` block regardless of whether it has a continuation or not).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy You're right, there are plenty of general "Why is this resource disposing in my asynchronous method". General guideline is: "If you're in a using block and invoking an asynchronous TAP method inside it, you should always `await` on it".

Comment: Are you not able to use `async / await`?  .NET 4.5 is not available for this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are disposing of the `networkStream` and `tcpClient` before the write and read operations start or have time to work.

With .NET 4.0, you need to do something as complex as this (this is something to start with, it needs more work):

```
var byteArray = MessageToByteArray(message, Encoding.UTF8);

var tcpClient = new TcpClient();

NetworkStream networkStream = null;

try
{
    tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5000);

    networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
}
catch
{
    ((IDisposable)tcpClient).Dispose();
    throw;
}

byte[] read_buffer = new byte[50];

Action dispose_action = () =>
{
    ((IDisposable)tcpClient).Dispose();
    networkStream.Dispose();
};

var write_task = networkStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

write_task
    .ContinueWith(wt =>
    {
        var read_task = networkStream.ReadAsync(read_buffer, 0, read_buffer.Length);


        read_task.ContinueWith(rt =>
        {
            //See if rt task is successful and if so, process read data here

            dispose_action();
        });

    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

write_task.ContinueWith(wt => dispose_action, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

The main idea of the code above is that you don't dispose of the TCP client and the network stream object until the read/write operations are done.

Imagine how complex this code would become if you want to read multiple times in some kind of loop.

With .NET 4.5, you can use `async` and `await` to do something (simpler) like this:

```
static async Task SendMessageToServerAsync(string message)
{
    var byteArray = MessageToByteArray(message, Encoding.UTF8);
    using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            await networkStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            byte[] read_buffer = new byte[50];

            int read = await networkStream.ReadAsync(read_buffer, 0, read_buffer.Length);

            // do something with the read_buffer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He's targeting .NET 4.0.

Comment: It's a .NET 4.0 question, so if you're talking about `async/await`, at least mention Microsoft.Bcl.Async, or, better yet, rewrite using continuations - not that hard.

Comment: I take back the "not that hard" part. That's a pretty good base effort you have right there and clearly there is still some way to go. At the point where I need to chain multiple conditional continuations like this I'd bite the bullet and try to upgrade to 4.5, install Microsoft.Bcl.Async or (if I'm really, really desperate) take Stephen Toub's tweak of Jeffrey Richter's `AsyncEnumerator`, and run with that (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/30/9809774.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - my internet went down yesterday and I couldn't access this post until now. This was very helpful. Can someone pls answer my second question, i.e.  `is FromAsync inside my Read method guaranteed to return the entire message from the server`

Comment: @user2635088, no, I don't think this is the case. Do you know for sure that the size of the message is 50 bytes? Even if it is the case, the stream might return less bytes than what you asked for. You should create some kind of loop to get more bytes. How much bytes to get depends on the protocol. For example are you expecting a message of a specific size? Or are you waiting to get some specific response? Anyway, doing such loop with .NET 4.0 is going to be hard. I suggest you consider the alternatives.